# MVC3 Json: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, json

I use...

```
$.post("/StoreHtml", { 'html': $("#txtHtml").val(), , function (data) { });
```

... to store html user enters, but method above fails with an

> "A potentially dangerous Request.Form
>   value was detected from the client".

How do I encode the html before sending it? ... and how do I decode it in vb.net?

Thanks!
Mojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use escape(htmlString) in the clintside (javescript) and HttpUtility.UrlDecode(htmlStringEncoded, System.Text.Encoding.Default()) in server side, then it works.

Any better suggestions or is this the best way?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth looking into

```
Server.HtmlDecode()
```